# An example of preferences over a countable set that cannot be represented by a utility function

Tags: preferences

Give an example of preferences over a countable set in which the preferences cannot be represented by a utility function that returns only integers as values.

I know a utility function exist that represents preference over a countable  set. I know a few types of preferences such as lexicographic, monotonic, quasi linear. I have always dealt with utility function assuming preferences are represented by that utility function. So how to solve this question?

Comment: What countable means? It can be finite countable? Or only infinite countable?

Comment: Both cases u can take

Comment: I'll give you a tip first, and if you still can't solve the problem, comment later on.

Comment: Ok.thnx fr the tips in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a proposition that says:

> If there is a function $u: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that represents the preference relation $\succsim$, then $\succsim$ is rational.

So, the contrapositive form of this statement is:

> If $\succsim$ isn't rational, then all functions $u$ don't represent $\succsim$.

So, it's a good approach to create a preference relation that isn't rational, i.e., the preference must violate transitivity or completeness.

Comment: Whatever your example is, it's probably wrong. The question assumes the relation is transitive and complete.